# dependent chained-up if-statements

Tags: c, if-statement

Let's take this C-code example:

```
int ID = 0;
if(  (Check(&ID) == ERROR) 
   ||(ID == -1)
){
   return ERROR;
}
```

Do you have any guarantee that `(Check(&ID) == ERROR)` is *checked* **before** `(ID == -1)` ?

(`ID = -1` would be an error-state, set by the function `Check`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because there is a *sequence point* between evaluation of first and second operand of `||` operator.

[N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 5.1.2.3 Program execution, paragraph 3 says:

> The presence of a sequence point
>   between the evaluation of expressions A and B implies that every value computation and
>   side effect associated with A is sequenced before every value computation and side effect
>   associated with B.

N1570  6.5.14 Logical OR operator, paragraph 4 says:

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the
>   second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first
>   and second operands. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is
>   not evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do. For an expression of the form `x || y`, `y` is only evaluated if `x` evaluates to 0.

This is called *short-circutting*, and also applies to `&&`.

Your parentheses are also superfluous: the same applies to the equivalent (and, in my opinion, clearer)

`if (Check(&ID) == ERROR || ID == -1)`